# How to fit image 100% in textangular by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, textangular

Initially when I drag an image into text area, it looks like this:

[image]

When I select 100% through my options, it fits to the frame like below:

[image]

What I want: when I drag and drop my image, it fits to 100% width by default, as showed in image 2. I am using `textangular`.

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

My HTML:

```
<text-angular id="textangular_group" ng-model="vm.creategroup.desc" ta-toolbar="vm.options"></text-angular>
```

Comment: Please show your code effort

Comment: checkout [textAngular Directives](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Directives), all you need is to use `taFileDrop` and set `style="width: 100%;"`, [how to use `taFileDrop`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816253/textangular-filedrophandler-documentation#answer-28035904)